# How to return vectors lists (vector<Point2f>) from JNI to Java?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am new to Android+OpenCV+JNI development. I am trying to find out the largest contour 
here is my native code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
    Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3Native_FindSquares
    (JNIEnv* env, jobject, jlong addrRgba, jint draw) {

    Mat& image = *(Mat*) addrRgba;
    int thresh = 50, N = 4;
    int found = 0;
    Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
    pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols / 2, image.rows / 2));
    pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
    vector < vector<Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for (int c = 1; c < 3; c++) {
        int ch[] = { c, 0 };
        mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
        // try several threshold levels
        for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
            // hack: use Canny instead of zero threshold level.
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if (l == 0) {
                // apply Canny. Take the upper threshold from slider
                // and set the lower to 0 (which forces edges merging)
                Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh, 5);
                // dilate canny output to remove potential
                // holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));
            } else {
                // apply threshold if l!=0:
                //     tgray(x,y) = gray(x,y) < (l+1)*255/N ? 255 : 0
                gray = gray0 >= (l + 1) * 255 / N;
            }

            // find contours and store them all as a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
            vector<Point> approx;
            // test each contour
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {

                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx,
                        arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.02, true);

                // square contours should have 4 vertices after approximation
                // relatively large area (to filter out noisy contours)
                // and be convex.
                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if (approx.size() == 4 && fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000
                        && isContourConvex(Mat(approx))) {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
                        // find the maximum cosine of the angle between joint edges
                        double cosine = fabs(
                                angle(approx[j % 4], approx[j - 2],
                                        approx[j - 1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    // if cosines of all angles are small
                    // (all angles are ~90 degree) then write quandrange
                    // vertices to resultant sequence
                    if (maxCosine < 0.3) {

                        circle(image, approx[0], 5, Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3,
                                4, 0);
                        circle(image, approx[1], 5, Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3,
                                4, 0);
                        circle(image, approx[2], 5, Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3,
                                4, 0);
                        circle(image, approx[3], 5, Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3,
                                4, 0);
                        //rectangle(image, approx[0], approx[2], Scalar(0,255,0,255), 5, 4, 0);

                        //Center of this rectangle
                        int x = (int) ((approx[0].x + approx[1].x + approx[2].x
                                + approx[3].x) / 4.0);
                        int y = (int) ((approx[0].y + approx[1].y + approx[2].y
                                + approx[3].y) / 4.0);

                        if ((int) draw) {
                            //outline
                            line(image, approx[0], approx[1],
                                    Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);
                            line(image, approx[1], approx[2],
                                    Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);
                            line(image, approx[2], approx[3],
                                    Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);
                            line(image, approx[3], approx[0],
                                    Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255), 1, 4, 0);
                        }
                        /// Get the moments
                        vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
                        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                            mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);
                        }

                        ///  Get the mass centers:
                        vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());

                        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                            mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00,
                                    mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
                        }
                        /// Draw contours
                        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                            circle(image, mc[i], 10, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1,
                                    CV_AA, 0);

                        }

                        found = 1;
                        jint result = (jint) found;
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    jint result = (jint) found;
    return result;
}
```

And I
am calling this native method from java code as

```
public native void FindFeatures(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
```

Everything works fine for me. I am returning int from native code Java code. My doubt is how can I return vector(which is 'mc' object in my method) from native code to Java. Please help me to find out the way to return  vectors lists from JNI to Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector<Point2f>` corresponds to `MatOfPoint2f` in Java which is a derived class of `Mat`.

Use the `vector` to `Mat` conversion function as in opencv repo([1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.11/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/converters.cpp#L151))

```
void vector_Point2f_to_Mat(vector<Point2f>& v_point, Mat& mat)
{
    mat = Mat(v_point, true);
}
```